# Standard deviation of a Random Variable (with respect to 3 other random variables)

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, standard-deviation

**I have the following problem**

> Assume that you have three independent Random Variables X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub> and X<sub>3</sub>.
> The `expected value` for each Random Variable is `3` and the `standard deviation` is `2`.
> Determine the `standard deviation` for the Random Variable Y = X<sub>1</sub> - 5⋅X<sub>2</sub> + 2⋅X<sub>3</sub> + 4.
> Hint: Variance[X] = V[X] = the square of the standard deviation = 2<sup>2</sup> = 4

I know how to do this for two variables (because there is a formula for this).
 But how do I do this for **three** random variables?

Can someone please help me solve the problem or give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Come on! the formula doesn't changes if you have 2 or 20 rv's.

$$\mathbb{V}[X_1-5X_2+2X_3+4]=\mathbb{V}[X_1]+25\mathbb{V}[X_2]+4\mathbb{V}[X_3]$$

this if, as is in your case, the rv's are independent (it is enough they are incorrelated)

Comment: but how does the answer become 11.0 (2√30) ? I can't see it

Comment: @AugustJelemson: $$\mathbb{V}[Y]=4+25\cdot4+4\cdot4=120=5\cdot3\cdot2^3$$

$$\sigma_Y=\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(Y)}=2\sqrt{5\cdot3\cdot2}=2\sqrt{30}$$

Comment: thanks tommik:)